# Why dataframe describe() method dosn't show all of the columns details after merge method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two csv file of datasets and I select some datas from first and marge them with the second dataset and replace to first one. so now I have new columns in my first datasets and now I need the average of one column what is new after marge. But when I use mean method or describe method they dosen't show that column details.

```
   dfgdp = pd.read_csv('../datasets/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv')
   dfgdp.rename(columns = {'GDP (BILLIONS)':'gdp', 'COUNTRY':'country'}, inplace = True)
   dfgdp = dfgdp[dfgdp['gdp']>1000]
   dfgdp = pd.merge(dfgdp, dfmig, how='inner', on='country')
   dfgdp.describe()
```

That show the 4 columns but I have 8 columns in my table.

Comment: Set `include='all'` and try again. If that doesn't work, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @cs95 thats work. but it show mean of that column `NaN` while that have no NaN data.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't comment any further because I have no clue what the data is or what it looks like.